# Node http get request can't handle Hebrew content

Tags: node.js, http

When using get Request, there are question mark instead of hebrew:

Bellow is a snippet of the code invoking during the request:

```
var req = ((/^https/.test(url))?https:http).request(opts,function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            msg.statusCode = res.statusCode;
            msg.headers = res.headers;
            msg.payload = "";
            res.on('data',function(chunk) {
                msg.payload += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end',function() {
                node.send(msg);
                node.status({});
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found out the solution, although it's very specific:
we need to require iconv and correctly handle the decoding:

```
var req = ((/^https/.test(url))?https:http).request(opts,function(res) {
            //res.setEncoding('binary');
            msg.statusCode = res.statusCode;
            msg.headers = res.headers;
            msg.payload = "";
            res.on('data',function(chunk) {
                msg.payload += iconv.decode(new Buffer(chunk), "Windows-1255");
                console.log(msg.payload);
            });
            res.on('end',function() {
                node.send(msg);
                node.status({});
            });
        });
```